# Can Unity Editor enter PlayMode without reloading a script

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am writing an Unity editor script that creates TCP server accepts requests from other application, but I found out that "clicking" play mode reloads my editor scripts which will interrupts the connection by re-initializing my server. Is there any way Unity Editor can stop reloading this particular script and makes it up running at all time?

```
    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    static void InitializeOnLoadMethod()
    {
        if (m_Server == null)
        {
            EditorApplication.update += Update;
            Debug.Log("starting");
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipAdress);
            m_Server = new TcpListener(ip, port);
            m_Server.Start();
            Debug.Log("Sever started");
            Debug.Log(ip);
            Debug.Log(port);


            //Wait for async client connection 
            m_Server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ClientConnected, null);
            OnServerStarted?.Invoke();
        }
```

In other words, is there a way to keep all my static variables and my editor coroutines after PlayMode is invoked? I did some search and I think domain reloading has caused it

Comment: I think my Question is how to keep my thread continue to run when entering play mode, also keeping my static variables

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong way. Play mode and Edit mode should be different, they should be isolated from each other. So better rethink your idea.

Comment: Check this out https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/DomainReloading.html

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this and don't have Unity on this PC to test, but can you gate it by using the *isPlaying* check:

```
if (!Application.isPlaying)
{
    // Do your server stuff here
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-isPlaying.html

In other words, don't run the code while the game is playing, which is true when you hit the Play button?

Comment: Actually my purpose is that I want my server up while the game is playing as well, but by clicking "Play", it reloads all my script and reset all my static variables

Comment: I tried your method but somehow the within still being executed

Comment: OK, so maybe I'm misunderstanding, but you want to initialise your server when Unity first boots up (Hence the InitializeOnLoadMethod) but you don't want it to reset those variables in the editor, but you do want to initialise the server in a packaged build?

Can you not use an editor define to knock out the code in editor in that case?

`#if WITH_EDITOR
if (!Application.isPlaying)
#endif
{
    // Your code here
}`

(Sorry, not able to format that nicely in this reply)

Comment: Actually I just realised you are using static variables. I don't think you can have static vars which persist between editor and game environments like that in Unity. I don't know the specifics of how Unity handles static editor variables, but maybe this thread would be of use:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/716691/setting-static-variables-in-editor-script.html

Comment: yeah...I found a way around not intialize twice with !EditorApplication.isPlayingOrWillChangePlaymode, but my static variables like client and server will lose after play is pressed also along with my editor coroutines... I am trying to build a server that can easily play/stop control unity with tcp connections